# issue in atom while building perceptron

Tags: python, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, atom-editor, perceptron

I'm building a perceptron using Atom Editor, and it is almost done, however when I run my code I receive the error messages

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sklearn.linear_model
[Finished in 0.503s]
```

I have installed sklearn.linear_model already, multiple times, as well as a lot of other software, so was wondering what the cause of this error message can be. I am new to this software, so it is very likely my mistake is something elementary.

Comment: How are you running your code? What operating system is this? How did you install Python? How did you install the third-party packages like `sklearn`?

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing an import problem. You are trying to import a library of which python cannot locate. This means that the package is either:

A) Not installed correctly

B) Has not been installed in the correct location

C) The root dependency of `sklearn` cannot be found.

Do you have the root package of `sklearn` installed or do you only have the sub-package installed?

Have you checked you are installing to the correct Python directory when installing?

Did any errors show up during the installation of the sub-package?

These are all probable causes for why Python is failing to import `sklearn`.